# Is it possible to have a different directory structure than the upstream but still be relatively easy to keep in sync?

Tags: git

If I have project A as the original project and project B is my forked version, can B have a different folder structure yet still be able to fetch from upstream without git trying to create new folders every time to match the upstream?

Is such a thing possible, and if not, can something similar to it be done?

Comment: Well you may play with subtree merge and you may or may not be satisfied depending on your needs and customs as well as complexity of the rearrange

Answer (score -1):

No, git relies on the 2 repositories to have the same directory and file structure and names, as that is the only way for it to identify changed, added, or removed files/folders.